# How to persist data across multiple iOS devices accessed via Facebook authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, networking, heroku

I have an iOS app using Swift that uses Core Data to store user data on thousands of objects. I also have FB Auth working. My question is, how do I make it so that the user data would persist even when they switch phones and log in using FB on a separate phone? It doesn't seem that FB will offer me such data persistence. I'm looking at making a server on Heroku with Vapor. Then I could use the user's e-mail as a way to identify the user... but it doesn't seem secure?

Any suggestions on easiest solution?

Comment: Checkout how WhatsApp and Telegram implement this

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)... Instead of using e-mail to authenticate users, you should deal with tokens. Firebase will provide you a great data flow in easiest manner.